# two @MdelAttributes are causing some issue

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I have two forms in my one page one form is

```
<form:form commandName="foo" class="form" action="/app/foo">
    <form:input id="name" path="name" type="text"/>
    <button>OK</button>
</form:form>
```

and other form is

```
<form:form commandName="bar" class="form">
    <form:input path="title"/>
    <form:input path="description"/>
    <button>OK</button>
</form:form>
```

I want to submit these forms separately when I submit the first form I redirect it to the same page after adding some data to second form I submit that as well, In my controller I have

```
@Controller
public class FooBarController {     

    @ModelAttribute("foo")
    public Foo constructFoo() {
        return new Foo();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("bar")
    public Bar constructBar() {
        return new Bar();
    }       

    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addFoo(@ModelAttribute("foo") Foo foo) {
        fooService.save(foo);
        return "redirect:/foo";
    } 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addBar(@ModelAttribute("bar") Bar bar) {          
        barService.save(bar);   
        return "redirect:/";
    } 

}
```

in above scenario the `addFoo()` is executed and `Foo` is saved but when I try to save `bar` in `addBar()` it does not save any thing, no errors no exceptions and no any data insertion.

Comment: where is tha action mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Mention action for the second form

```
<form:form commandName="bar" class="form" action="/app/bar">
    <form:input path="title"/>
    <form:input path="description"/>
    <button>OK</button>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the second `@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)` to :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/bar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

and as Vipin cp said add an action to your from :

```
<form:form commandName="bar" class="form" action="/app/bar">
<form:input path="title"/>
<form:input path="description"/>
<button>OK</button>
```